# Where Can I Find Suitable Buyers?

Tags: company-management

I am planning to sell my company, We have around 85 people working in various technologies. Mainly we have strong expertise on php/mysql, joomla, wordpress, magento and opencart. (We are one of the leading expert in Web Technology)
Where can I find suitable buyers to my company. I am not able to find suitable buyers for my company.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about freelancing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Freelancing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with freelancing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a network of people who regularly buy or sell businesses  then you may require a broker to help set up a deal.

A broker usually has the expertise and contacts to find suitable suitors for your business as well as offer insights on the valuation of your company.

You might want to find a specialist business broker in technology as they will have more suitable domain knowledge of all the legal requirements and technical challenges of transferring ownership of a large business.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find those brokers ?

Comment: Have you tried a search on LinkedIn?

Comment: It's the same as finding a real estate agent, lawyer or an accountant. See if anyone you know can recommend one, else search online and do your homework.